# RMarkdown - second inline code shows code block instead of value

Tags: r, r-markdown, inline-code

I am trying to show just a couple of variable values, using inline code in RMarkdown. 
The first inline code shows the value correctly (the number 3), but the second shows the code block instead of the expected value (datos[2] instead of the number 9). 
Both use the same sintaxis. 
The wrong output occurs when output is to HTML. Outputing to Word works ok. Any idea why does this behavior occur and how can I fix it? 
I am using R 3.3.3, RStudio 1.1.419, MacOS X Yosemite. 
The code is as follows:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
datos <- c(3,9,4,7)
```
The first value in datos is `r datos[1]` and the second is `r datos[2]`.
````

The output is:

```
Untitled
The first value in datos is 3 and the second is datos[2].
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: What is the issue exactly? I just tried running your code and it works just fine, producing the desired output.

Untitled
The first value in datos is 3 and the second is 9.
I am using R 4.0.2, Rstudio 1.3.1056

Answer (score 0):

Add a `r` letter in second block.

```
The first value in datos is `r datos[1]` and the second is `r datos[2]`.
```

`r` here works as a statement to tell R to run this code,

`datos[2]`

and return the number here.

Comment: Yes, thanks Jiaxiang. I've noticed the error and corrected it, and once corrected, this code behaves correctly, but I uploaded this just as an example. In my real code, much longer than this, the code was correctly written, but the output is still wrong.Thanks!

Comment: The actual code shows a data.frame value in the form `r datos[3,2]` and `r datos[3,1]`. The first inline code chunk shows the value correctly, but the second shows the code block. As I stated above, this error occurs only in the HTML output, not in the Word output.

Comment: @MarceloM I face the similar problem, it is the bug in html output instead of docx, pdf output. I recommend you use `pull()` method to extract the specific number you need, this is my current way I use to solve this sort of problems.